# How do I conneect to pg after switch from Mysql to postgres on Heroku; PG Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I switched my rails 4.2 app from mysql to postgres on Heroku. Everything works fine locally after the switch and it runs perfectly on postgre but I get the following message when I try to do a migration on Heroku:

```
 PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
  Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

My Heroku Env Variables are:

```
 HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK_URL:     postgres://bbczqezwwklzqp:1jBcxlGoibmUuriNufTTx2fFOk@ec2-54-163-248-144.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dcit0akvuomjtr
 LANG:                           en_US.UTF-8
 NEW_RELIC_AGGRESSIVE_KEEPALIVE: 1
 NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY:          aaca6674945ff7f7f542e6db625cb7a509ad7746
 NEW_RELIC_LOG:                  stdout
 PAPERTRAIL_API_TOKEN:           Ckbl776aK5kMKkml7K41
 RACK_ENV:                       staging
 RAILS_ENV:                      staging
 SECRET_KEY_BASE:                3d21b4717dc1755ea7c924b6ad6e3d8770b0099b4d87892dbebd92b6f7b1c287831fd564115de2650bdf7339c472e7dd83a4b56ab6567863d9885f2097709065
```

My database.yml is:

```
 development: &default
   adapter: postgresql
   database: lawgix_development
   encoding: utf8
   host: localhost
   min_messages: warning
   pool: 2
   timeout: 5000

 test:
   <<: *default
   database: lawgix_test

 staging:
   <<: *default
   database: lawgix_staging

 production:
   <<: *default
   database: lawgix
```

Comment: How are you running the migration on Heroku?  `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to configure `DATABASE_URL` env variable in Heroku. Without that, Rails is falling back to your `database.yml` and trying to a non-existing database in `localhost`

You can try this command:

```
 heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK_URL
```

or just define it to mimic `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK_URL` yourself.